# stuck at understanding "$worksheet->add_write_handler(qr[\w], \&store_string_widths);" line in the below piece of code

Tags: excel, perl, csv

My final goal for my first perl program :To create an excel sheet for reporting purpose and email the sheet as an attachment.

I have reached till creating a csv file. now i wanted to convert this to excel sheet and autofit the content.

I have an example code in our environment,could someone take time to explain each line on the below code, it would be very grateful.

outputfile,urloutputfile,scomoutputfile - are the csv files, now being converted to excel sheets.

Please explain how an element is being passed to the other function also.

```
my $parser = Text::CSV::Simple->new;
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($auditxl);
my @totcsvlist;
push(@totcsvlist,$outputfile);
push(@totcsvlist,$urloutputfile);
push(@totcsvlist,$scomoutputfile);
my @data;
my $subject = 'worksheet';
foreach my $totcsvlis (@totcsvlist)
{
    undef @data;
    chomp($totcsvlis);
    if ($totcsvlis eq $outputfile) { $subject="Service Status"; }
    if ($totcsvlis eq $urloutputfile) { $subject="URL Status"; }
    if ($totcsvlis eq $scomoutputfile) { $subject="SCOM Agent Status"; }
    @data = $parser->read_file($totcsvlis);
    my $headers = shift @data;
    import_data($workbook, $subject, $headers, \@data);
}
$workbook->close();


sub autofit_columns {
    my $worksheet = shift;
    my $col       = 0;
    for my $width (@{$worksheet->{__col_widths}}) {
        $worksheet->set_column($col, $col, $width) if $width;
        $col++;
    }
}

sub import_data {
    my $workbook  = shift;
    my $base_name = shift;
    my $colums    = shift;
    my $data      = shift;
    my $limit     = shift || 50_000;
    my $start_row = shift || 1;
    my $bold = $workbook->add_format();
    $bold->set_bold(1);
    $bold->set_bg_color('gray');
    $bold->set_border();
    my $celbor = $workbook->add_format();
    $celbor->set_border();
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($base_name);
    $worksheet->add_write_handler(qr[\w], \&store_string_widths);
    my $w = 1;
    $worksheet->write('A' . $start_row, $colums, $bold);
    my $i = $start_row;
    my $qty = 0;
    for my $row (@$data) {
        $qty++;

        $worksheet->write($i++, 0, $row,$celbor);
    }
    autofit_columns($worksheet);
    warn "Convereted $qty rows.";
    return $worksheet;
}

sub autofit_columns {

    my $worksheet = shift;
    my $col       = 0;

    for my $width (@{$worksheet->{__col_widths}}) {

        $worksheet->set_column($col, $col, $width + 5) if $width;
        $col++;
    }
}

sub store_string_widths {

    my $worksheet = shift;
    my $col       = $_[1];
    my $token     = $_[2];

    return if not defined $token;       # Ignore undefs.
    return if $token eq '';             # Ignore blank cells.
    return if ref $token eq 'ARRAY';    # Ignore array refs.
    return if $token =~ /^=/;           # Ignore formula

    return if $token =~ m{^[fh]tt?ps?://};
    return if $token =~ m{^mailto:};
    return if $token =~ m{^(?:in|ex)ternal:};


    my $old_width    = $worksheet->{__col_widths}->[$col];
    my $string_width = string_width($token);

    if (not defined $old_width or $string_width > $old_width) {

        $worksheet->{__col_widths}->[$col] = $string_width;
    }

    return undef;
}


sub string_width {

    return length $_[0];
}
```

I have tried to search and read modules used in the above code, but over head.
https://github.com/jmcnamara/spreadsheet-writeexcel/blob/master/examples/autofit.pl
-- has similar code and has provided a basic over view. but i would like to understand in detail.

Thank you so much in advance.
Regards,
Kaushik KM

Comment: Asking someone to "explain each line" probably won't get you any answers. Do do this well we would have to know exactly what you already understand and what you don't. Better ask more specific questions.

Comment: You are correct, but as this was my first one.. i wanted one example to be explained in detail and then i would get a grip to do more.

but to be specific :
after calling the function "import_data($workbook, $subject, $headers, \@data);"


what does the below line says ?
$worksheet->add_write_handler(qr[\w], \&store_string_widths); ???

what is qr[\w] mean ?
and what is \& mean in \&store_string_widths ?

Comment: i will analyze the code based on your answer, and will ask the next one.
waiting for your ans. thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you get that code from in the first place? Did you write it?

Comment: So qr[\w] is a bit weird. Perl can use any special character to delimit the start and end of a regex pattern. / is standard but is annoying when dealing with paths and urls so ! is also often used. When [ is used as the starting delimiter ] because the ending delimiter, they ALSO act as the start and end of a character class. I've never seen it actually done before. This implementation is functionally identical to qr/\w/. qr// is a saved and cached regex pattern.

Comment: \&store_string_widths is a coderef, a reference to the function named store_string_widths. It is typically called as $coderef->(@args);

Comment: Note: `undef @data;` is a very inefficient way to do `@data = ();` (empty an array). It releases memory related to `@data` back to the interpreter so that next time you assign to `@data`  memory need be acquired again (and perhaps the array structure need be re-built).

Comment: @MattJacob no i dint write the above code. it is there is our current production environment.(written by my senior) and i was reading and understanding it, to write my own code which does a different reporting work,but wanted piece of code to convert CSV to XL

Comment: @lod i wanted to know what does qr/\w/ mean ? what does it do ?
i guess the answer is given by Dave Cross below.
thanks for ---undef @data;----- i will change it to  --@data = ();--

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the documentation for the `add_write_handler()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#add_write_handler(-$re,-$code_ref-)) method call. It says:

> **add_write_handler( $re, $code_ref )**
>
> This method is used to extend the Excel::Writer::XLSX write() method
>   to handle user defined data.

And later, it says:

> The `add_write_handler()` method take two arguments, `$re`, a regular
>   expression to match incoming data and `$code_ref` a callback function
>   to handle the matched data

So, here you have a method call that takes two arguments. The first is a regex that tells the object what type of data this new write handler is used for. The second is a reference to the subroutine that should be used as the write handler for data that matches the regex.

The regex you have is `qr[\w]`. The actual regex bit of that is `\w`. And that just means "match a word character". The `qr` is to compile a string into a regex and the `[ ... ]` is just the delimiter for the regex string (`qr/.../` is one of a class of Perl operators that allows you to use almost any character you want as a delimiter).

So, if your object is called on to write some data that contains at least one word character, the subroutine which is given as the second argument is used. But we take a reference to the subroutine.

Elsewhere in your code, you define the `store_string_widths()` subroutine. Subroutines in Perl are a lot like variables, and that means that they have their own sigil. The sigil for a subroutine is `&` (like the `$` for scalar and `@` for arrays). You very rarely need the `&` in modern Perl code, so you won't see it used very often. One place that it is still used, is when we take a reference to a subroutine. You take a reference to any variable by putting a slash in front of the variable's full name (like `\@array` or `\%hash`) and subroutines are no different. So `\&store_string_widths` means "get a reference to the subroutine called `store_string_widths()`".

You say that this is your first Perl program. I have to say that this feels a little ambitious for your first Perl code. I don't cover references at all in my two-day beginners course and on my intermediate course I cover most references, but on mention subroutine references in passing. If you can understand references enough to get this all working, then I think you're doing really well.

Comment: Hi @Dave Cross,
thanks for looking in.
As i mentioned above, the above code is not written by me, it was written by my senior.i am just trying to understand it.

\w  --> means to match any "word character" - thanks for this,
i will try to explain the code at main parts, please correct if i am wrong

Comment: 1)in the first iteration of  `foreach my $totcsvlis (@totcsvlist)` loop
lets say $outputfile is matched,so
 `@data = $parser->read_file($totcsvlis);` - is executed and @data will contain the reference to each of the line of the file $totcsvlis  
2)`my $headers = shift @data;` - first line refrence will be assigned to $headers.
3)`import_data($workbook, $subject, $headers, \@data);` - calling the function import_data by passing the above 4 variables..



4)`my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($base_name);` - this will add a sheet to the work book

Comment: 5)`$worksheet->add_write_handler(qr[\w], \&store_string_widths);`
this will write the added sheet getting the data from where ?
and Please explain what is `store_string_widths` function is doing ?

Comment: @kaushikkm: Apologies for not replying sooner. I've been on holiday and avoiding the internet :-) `add_write_handler()` does not write anything. It adds a handler that is called whenever data is written elsewhere in the code. It's a slightly advanced topic that isn't really suitable for explaining in these comments. I suggest you ask the code's author to sit down with you and explain it.